# How to loop over index column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where I set an ID column as the index column. How do I loop through just that column? When I try iteritems or iterrows I always get a KeyError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrame object as index attribute you can use that to loop through the index

```py
[ind for ind in df.index]
```